# R/RStudio: .libPaths() does not append to or overwrite the library tree

Tags: r

I need to set the library path in R for a single use (i.e. I do not want and can't set it in `Rprofile.site` and can't put the additional packages into the default library).

I tried to append to and to overwrite the library path with `.libPaths()` but neither worked; the path remained unchanged. See my attempts below.

Since I have seen examples that effectively are the same as my attempts, I have a feeling that it might be an authorisation issue: I simply have no rights to change the path.

I have searched stackoverflow, but the questions/solutions do not match my problem. Any suggestions? And no, [turning it off and on again](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8) would not help.

My environment is Mac (High Sierra), R 3.4.3, RStudio 1.1.423, R newbie user (not `root`).

Thanks!

**Original path**

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library"
> .Library
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library"
```

**Trying to append**

```
> .libPaths( c( .libPaths(), "<some_other_valid_path>") )
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library"
> .Library
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library"
```

**Trying to overwrite**

```
> .libPaths("<some_other_valid_path>")
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library"
> .Library
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library"
```

Comment: Mind sharing the exact value of  `"<some_other_valid_path>"`? Are you, for instance, leaving on or removing any trailing `"/`" in the specification of the path?

Comment: I can't share the exact value, but it did not end with `/`. See, my answer below for explanation of the cause and solution.

Comment: Good to hear. If Dirk's answer solved your problem, you might want to give it a check mark to let others's know it's solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just confused yourself. Just add one directory to prepend:

```
R> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library" 
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"           
R> .libPaths("/tmp")
R> .libPaths()
[1] "/tmp"                    "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" 
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/library"           
R>
```

The new one comes first and *will therefore be used first* for an installation, or a search via `library()` etc.

You cannot overwrite from an existing session---that is like cutting the tree branch you are sitting on.

But do see `help(Startup)`.  There are other files, even on a per-current-directory level, you could use.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback, Dirk! I was indeed confused about how `.libPaths` works, thanks for the clarification.

Based on your example, I realised that issue was that I had no access to the additional directory. `.libPaths()` internally calls `dir.exists()` which returned `false` due to non-accessibility and thus the new directory was not added to path. I just need to figure out how to provide access.